# How to generate Ruby documentation using different template?

Tags: ruby, documentation-generation, rdoc

I want to generate the [Ruby documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/index.html) with [hanna](http://github.com/mislav/hanna/tree/master) template.

How to do that? Or where can I download it if it's available at all?

Using

`rdoc -o ~/doc --inline-source --line-numbers --format=html --template=hanna`

gives me docs with missing methods. It seems like it doesn't generate methods written in C.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out you just need to get the [Ruby source code](ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/), extract it, and then in the source directory, run something like this:

```
rdoc -o <output path> --inline-source --line-numbers --format=html --template=hanna
```

Answer (score 1):

In your ruby source directory, run

hanna -o  --inline-source --line-numbers --format=html

Comment: This worked for me. Specifically, `cd ruby-1.8.7-p248 ; hanna -o hannadoc --inline-source --line-numbers --fmt=html ; open hannadoc/index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

gem install mislav-hanna

Then just follow the steps in the readme:

http://github.com/mislav/hanna/blob/8eaeb062fae276b19eb86fa302e9ee446a06eef8/README.markdown

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rvm, this works:

```
$ gem install hanna
$ cd ~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.6-p383
$ hanna -o doc/api --inline-source --line-numbers --fmt=html
$ open doc/api/index.html
```